# Python Sequential asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I can't get my head around some of async bits. I have an async function which pulls some JSON (using aiohttp) and awaits on another and then another as follows:

```
    bgp_asn, source = await get_probe_data(session, probe_id)
    asn_name = await get_probe_bgp_data(session, bgp_asn)
```

The trouble I have is that these two are not sequential and `asn_name` returns None as a result of `bgp_asn` hasn't been received yet. What would you suggest around this problem / lack of my understanding?

Updated:

```
async def get_probe_bgp_data(session, bgp_asn):
    PROBE_BGP_QUERY = f"https://stat.ripe.net/data/as-overview/data.json?resource=AS{bgp_asn}"
    async with session.get(PROBE_BGP_QUERY, params=HEADER) as bgp_data:
        bgp_data_output = bgp_data.json()
        return bgp_data_output["data"]["holder"]

async def get_probe_data(session, probe_id):
PROBE_URL = f"https://atlas.ripe.net/api/v2/probes/{probe_id}"
async with session.get(PROBE_URL, params=HEADER) as probe_data:
    probe_data_output = await probe_data.json()
    return probe_data_output["asn_v4"], probe_data_output["address_v4"]
```

Following error is thrown:

```
return bgp_data_output["data"]["holder"]
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientResponse.json' was never awaited
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get_msr_data' was never awaited
```

Thank you

Comment: How exactly did you conclude that `get_probe_data()` doesn't finish? Do your functions perhaps contain `except:` clauses that hide the errors and return `None` in their place? It's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing the code.

Comment: Hi, it returns None. Isn't whole point of await to go on with next thing i.e "asn_name" would run without waiting on completion of previous function?

Comment: I understand that it returns None, but I am questioning the claim that it didn't finish its work without returning - that would depend on how `get_probe_data` is implemented, which you didn't show. *Isn't whole point of await to go on with next thing* - **no**, `await` means precisely the opposite, that you wait for the thing to finish and then continue. Of course, during that wait other coroutines can run.

Comment: OK, i've updated with relevant code.

Comment: In your current sample code, you need to `await` the call of `bgp_data.json` in `get_probe_bgp_data`: `await bgp_data.json()`

Comment: @Ajax1234 thank you! it's time to get new pair of glasses :)